# Adding a logo to our Stackexchange

Tags: feature-request

Many other StackExchange sites have a logo on the [traffic page](http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#traffic). How can we go about getting one of our own, as opposed to the default blue chatbox and M we have now?

Answer (score 5):

Monero Stack Exchange is still [in public beta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98617/monero). A site goes through several stages from proposal, definition, commitment, private & public beta, to finally the graduation ([explained that on reddit a while ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4dqr55/lets_graduate_the_ethereum_stack_exchange_before/?ref=share&ref_source=link)).

We are currently in public beta, this is the last and most important step *before* graduation. Your follow-up question will be probably, what do we have to do to succeed and graduate? It basically breaks down to a strong community both in terms of active users and [frequently questions asked per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/226837), about 10 per day on average.

Custom site themes and logos will be applied after graduation.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it looks like the sites with a logo all have graduated beta. If that is a requirement then we probably do not have the option yet.